# Extracting article ID from array key

Tags: php, arrays

I have created following array. The value `0.0053165` & `0.0052665` are the weight of the popular article.

The article ID is **`975`** and **`977`**

```
Array
(
    [weight] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [975] => 0.0053165
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [977] => 0.0052665
                )

        )

)
```

The issue is , i am trying to save the 1st article ID into the one variable and update that variable in DB.

How i can achieve this operation ?

Comment: `array_keys()`? `key()`? `foreach (... as $key => $value)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$res = array();    
foreach($weight as $key => $value)
  array_push($res, $key)
```

Comment: You must mean [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php), more specifically `array_push($res, $key);`

Comment: Oops, too much javascript these days, thanks!